# Is there an R function that compare the distribution of pairs of columns of a data frame by plotting them all in one square sheet

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, distribution

I have a data frame that can be created as follows.

```
dat <- data.frame(dens = c(rnorm(50), rnorm(50, 10, 5), rnorm(50, 5, 1), rnorm(50, 3,2))
              , group = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each = 50))
```

I am trying to compare the distribution of each possible pair of groups(a,b),(a,c), (a,d), (b,c), ... by plotting the distribution of each pair on top of each other.

I would like to have a sheet/frame in matrix form that have 16 slots so that each slot represent the distributions of let's say pair (a,b) and so on.

What I have now is the distribution plot of all 4 groups in one plot.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = dens, fill = group))+ 
              geom_density(alpha = 0.5)
```

Do you have any idea if I can create the 4 * 4 sheet of plots?

Comment: You mean something like `pairs(dat)`?

Comment: Hi, Actually the plot that I am looking for is as what you see in @JonSpring 's answer. But I can not reproduce that. Do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach that joins the data to itself, after nesting into groups. That way each group gets paired once with each other group (and itself), making it possible to plot each set against each other one in facets.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat_nested <- dat %>%
  nest(data = c(dens)) %>%    # Edit: better syntax to avoid warning msg
  mutate(all = 1)

dat_nested %>%
  full_join(dat_nested %>% 
              rename(group2 = group),
            by = "all") %>%
  unnest(cols = c(data.x, data.y),   # updated to preferred tidyr 1.0.0 syntax
         names_repair = make.unique) %>%  

  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = dens, fill = group), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_density(aes(x = dens.1, fill = group2), alpha = 0.5) +
  facet_grid(group ~ group2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi the plot that you have here is exactly what I want. But I am getting error while running your code. for the first part I am getting the following warning `Warning message:
All elements of ... must be named.
Did you want  data = c(dens)? ` and for second part I am getting this error `Error in rename(., group2 = group) : object 'group' not found` Do you know how can I fix it ?

Comment: Earlier version used syntax from earlier tidyr which is partly deprecated and produced warnings (but not errors) for me. Updated version uses tidyr 1.0.0 syntax and removed those warnings for me.

Comment: you are right I updated tidyr and it just returned warnings. I could replicate your plots thanks

Comment: I have one more question. In fact, the dat has been created as a toy example that represent my real data. In my real data I have 31 groups and when I run your code the plots are really small so that I can not compare the distribution of each group vs the other. Do you have any suggestion that I can apply to my real data in a way that I can plot the distribution of each group vs the other?

Comment: Probably not the best layout if you want to show all the data. Perhaps better to calculate summary stats (e.g. mean + SD) and plot all the variables on a scatter plot. Or calculate correlation / t.test between each group and plot a tile graph of those comparisons. Or use some criteria to pick just the "interesting" (as appropriate to your use case) distribution plots and only show those.